# Send same action as `cleos push action hello hi ...` in smart contract tutorial

Tags: smart-contract, rpc

I finished smart contract tutorial, and it worked well.
Now I'm trying to send same action as `cleos push action hello hi '["bob"]' -p user@active` in tutorial by using RPC API, cause need to implement push in other language(not JS).
Currently, I've found that  I need to generate JSON as abi-bin for now, so tried to send like:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
  "code": "hello",
  "action": "hi",
  "args": {
    "name": "user",
    "type": "account_name"
  }
}' \
  --request POST http://localhost:8888/v1/chain/abi_json_to_bin
```

but it failed. It returns:

```
{
   "code":500,
   "message":"Internal Service Error",
   "error":{
     "code":3015014,
     "name":"pack_exception",
     "what":"Pack data exception",
     "details":[]
   }
}
```

...and in chain, it prints:

```
2018-10-19T10:18:47.006 thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:581           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3015014 pack_exception: Pack data exception
Missing 'user' in variant object
{"f":"user"}
thread-0  abi_serializer.cpp:389 _variant_to_binary

{"type":"hi","var":{"name":"user","type":"account_name"}}
thread-0  abi_serializer.cpp:410 _variant_to_binary

{"type":"hi","var":{"name":"user","type":"account_name"}}
thread-0  abi_serializer.cpp:426 _variant_to_binary
'{"name":"user","type":"account_name"}' is invalid args for action 'hi'     code 'hello'. expected '[{"name":"user","type":"name"}]'
{"args": {"name":"user","type":"account_name"},"action":"hi","code":"hello","proto": [{"name":"user","type":"name"}]}
thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:1737 abi_json_to_bin
code: hello, action: hi, args: {"name":"user","type":"account_name"}
{"code":"hello","action":"hi","args":   {"name":"user","type":"account_name"}}
thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:1743 abi_json_to_bin
```

Could somebody give me a guide for correct request form?

Thanks.

Comment: don't you need to pass some authorization to the http api the same way you pass via cleos with `-p`? it'd help if you mentioned how it failed i.e. what error

Comment: @confused00 thanks! I just update detail logs...

Comment: @confused00 I added -p, but it returns same error.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the `args` command should be an array, even though it only has one element.

Try replacing this part:

```
  "args": {
    "name": "user",
    "type": "account_name"
  }
```

with this:

```
  "args": [{
    "name": "user",
    "type": "account_name"
  }]
```